# JSON Parsing swift, Always catch statement executing

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, parsing, cell

I have UITableViewController, i'm trying to parse data from url,
Always catch statement executing, that prints "something" in the console.
in Storyboard i added reuse identifier to the table view cell.

'''
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
final let url = URL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
private var posts = [Post]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadJson()
}

func downloadJson() {
    guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, response != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let tempPosts = try decoder.decode(Posts.self, from: data)
            print(tempPosts)
            self.posts = tempPosts.posts

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("something")
        }
    }.resume()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

}
'''

'''

```
class Posts: Codable {
    let posts: [Post]
    
    init(posts: [Post]) {
        self.posts = posts
    }
}

class Post: Codable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String
    
    init(userId: Int, id: Int, title: String, body: String) {
        self.userId = userId
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
    }
```

}
'''

Comment: `print("something")`=> `print("Error while parsing: \(error)")`. That's the first step (and important one).

Comment: Add the JSON response and Posts model that you're using to parse the data

Comment: After seeing the JSON at the URL, I guess that `decoder.decode(Posts.self, from: data)` => `decoder.decode([Posts].self, from: data)`, BUT that's speculation. We need the `Posts` code too, since there might be OTHER issues.

Comment: I have added model to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Post` model is,

```
struct Post: Codable {
    let userId, id: Int
    let title, body: String
}
```

Use **`[Posts].self`** instead of `Posts.self` while parsing the `data`.

```
let tempPosts = try decoder.decode([Post].self, from: data)
```

Comment: I have added model to my question, check please

Comment: Thank you, I used just one class for model

Comment: That's not how you make the Codable model for this JSON format. Use the one that I've added in the answer.

Comment: can you help me with parsing, how to parse only the first 30 elements of JSON that I fetching from URL?

Comment: Which 30 elements do you want?

Comment: First 30 elements [Posts, Posts...] from json that i fetching from url

Comment: You can get the first 30 posts using `let first30 = tempPosts[0..<30]`

Comment: Thank you very much self.posts = Array(tempPosts[0..<30])